# Stores and C# assembly dll files not being loaded

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, dll, in-app-purchase

I have recently tried adding **In App Purchase** into my Unity project. Unfortunately, it didn't show in the Components drop down menu. I could use the option to create IAP Button and perform code-less IAP configuration but it wasn't there in the menu. So I decided to configure IAP through script. But the script too throws some errors. The error goes like this:

**"Assembly 'Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll' will not be loaded due to errors: Reference has errors 'Stores'."**

Four errors just like the above one shows up for Assembly-CSharp.dll, Editor.dll and Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll

And then this one:
**"Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/UnityPurchasing/Bin/Stores.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'UnityEngine.UI'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector."**

I have tried re-installing In App Purchase package.

I have tried changing the API from .NET Standard 2.0 to .NET 4.x (and did the vice versa and still did not work)

Downgrading unity project isn't really a good idea but anyways I gave it a try but it just added to the already existing errors.

Upgrading to newer Unity version (alpha version) didn't help.

The error occurs whenever I initialize the ConfigurationBuilder referring StandardPurchasingModule.

```
public void InitializePurchasing()
{
    // If we have already connected to Purchasing ...
    if (IsInitialized())
    {
        // ... we are done here.
        return;
    }

    var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());


    builder.AddProduct(TWO_BOLTS, ProductType.Consumable);
    builder.AddProduct(FIVE_BOLTS, ProductType.NonConsumable);


    UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
}
```

**The worst part is that I am unable to use my scripts after writing the ConfigurationBuilder initialization code. Unity asks me to fix any compiler errors and assign a valid script. I have searched for the answer for so long. I am really stuck in here. Please help.**

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: I am using Unity 2019.2.0b2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be related to verison of Unity you using. You can follow progress of this issue on [official Unity issue tracker](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/dll-errors-in-iap-occur-when-upgrading-project-to-2019-dot-2-or-2019-dot-3).

If this issue is showstopper for you than cosider downgrading as you using beta verions of Unity and as [official site states](https://unity3d.com/beta/2019.2):

> As with any beta program, you’ll have early access to new features and
>   will be able to assist in the final steps of their development. That
>   means you’re likely to experience Unity as less stable than a final
>   version.

Comment: I re-built (by re-using assets) the project using Unity 2019.1.5f1. It is a stable version. There were no errors after adding In App Purchase. The issue seems to be solved. Thanks a lot.